# Can you customize the details you receive from a contact form? Php

Tags: php, styles, contact-form

I was wondering if you could put styles on the details you receive on your email from the contact form? I wanted to make the titles bolder. I made the contact form in .php

Answer (score 0):

Customising and styling is the work of CSS. Give the HTML tag a `class` or an `id` and in your style.css file which must have been linked in the `<head>` tag of your HTML file include

```
h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold; 
}
```

Check this CSS tutorial on [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp) for more reference

Comment: For PHP? I was asking about the email that I will receive from the contact form?

Comment: Sorry, you can't make titles bolder using PHP. You need to do this with HTML and CSS. Give your input tag a class or id and follow the instruction I gave earlier.

Comment: Ohhhh okay. I can connect the php file with CSS?? Sorry I'm really lost lol

Answer (score 0):

What you receive from the contact form is only the *data*, its representation is done separately when you send it to yourself as an email.

As an example, you might also want to store the contact form data in a database. Would you also save the styling with it? Of course not. You would store the raw data, and style it when you make that into an email to send out.

With email HTML content, you need to have all your CSS in the `head` tag or even better inline for each of your elements. That's because CSS in your email can sometimes be tricky in terms of which email provider allows what in your HTML. E.g. you could have

```
<h4 style="font-weight: bold">Contact subject </h4>
```